# Why does an 18 volt cordless drill charger output 21 volts?

Tags: battery-charging

The charger says on the back that it outputs 21 volts and 400mAh. 21 volts seem too high for an 18 volt battery. Wouldn't that damage the battery?

Comment: Are the 21V open circuit ?

Comment: Do you mean milliamperes, or milliampere hours?  Milliamperes is a measure of current.  Milliampere hours is a measure of capacity and would normally apply to batteries, not chargers.

Comment: 18V battery means 18V nominal. Batteries are not like gas tanks where the tank can provide exactly the same amount of power when full right up until the tanks runs dry. It's more like a human being performing work: The more tired you get the less power you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like 18V lithium with 5 cells in series.

The pack has a nominal voltage of 18V or 3.6V per cell, but cells are fully charged when they have 4.2V per cell, or 21V.

Answer (score 1):

In order to charge a battery, the charger must obviously be able to provide a voltage greater than the nominal terminal voltage of that battery if it is to drive a current into the cells.
A well designed charger will contain circuitry that adjusts the voltage it delivers until it the current is limited to whatever rating the charger can supply or the battery specified requiring (whichever is less).
The 21V is probably the maximum voltage the charger can supply, when charging this will be less. Remember that whilst charging the terminal voltage of the battery will rise above its nominal voltage and the extra voltage capability is needed to overcome this.
Again, a well designed charger will not damage your battery if it is the correct one for the job.